# PS4 drastic connection speed drop recently

Tags: ps4, networking

Before I start, YES, I know that there are 101 pages of similar problems and similar error, but no clear steps are given, nor explanations. So:

We have had our PS4 for 6 months, and in that time i have occasionally checked internet speeds. Our modems average, via [Ookla Speed Test](http://www.speedtest.net), is **~14Mb/s down** and **~750Kb/s up**. The PS4 network test (Again I will save myself pain: *I know it is unreliable, I simply compare it to itself*) usually comes up with **~10Mb/s down** and **~650Kb/s up**.

Now, that was until recently. A few weeks back, a local server went down (Telstra is our ISP, an Australian one for anyone who doesn't know), and we had no internet for 24 hours. Since sometime between then and now, the PS4 speed has dropped to **~2.5Mb/s down** although **~700Kb/s up** - yes, that has apparently increased. We now get irritatingly persistent lag issues, and while still playable we are constantly reminded by Battlefront of our 'weak connection' in the top right of the screen. However it is important to note that the [Ookla Speed Test](http://www.speedtest.net) still gives the same results, so it is our PS4.

### Notes:

- During the PlayStation network test, it occasionally says we have NAT type 3, rather than 2 (only rarely)
- It claims that our router doesn't support IP fragmentation, which it never used to say.
- We use wireless rather than cable, ethernet isn't available (only one port in the whole house).
- We're in Australia if you couldn't tell, which is why 14 is actually a great speed for us - Australia has shocking speeds.

### Attempted Fixes:

- Changed DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4, didn't change anything
- Changed PS4 MTU size to 1470, incredibly fractional increase in DL speed
- Changed router MTU to 1500 and 1450, neither helped.
- Something perhaps important: our 2.4/5Ghz networks were both set to half their maximum bandwidth, but **increasing them to full did nothing**
- For the IT Crowd fans, yes I tried turning it off and on again, both the PS4 and router.

What I would like is a succinct answer, with (preferably) every possible unmentioned fix in order of likely effectiveness, and why it is done - mostly because every other page seems to be a reddit page which requires an hour of reading with no benefit, and I feel like there should be a good list of options out there for everyone. Thank you in advance.

### AND

if this is the wrong site for this question please just tell me rather than reporting it, I wasn't sure which to use.

Comment: Have you tried restoring PS4's default factory settings? I don't know if that will help but it definitely helped me when my DS4 refused to connect to my PS4. You could also try moving the PS4 and the router closer together or make a [tin foil signal booster](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ARY3m.jpg) for your router. Best of luck to you!

Comment: The only thing is that my PS4 connects fine to the router, it just seems to be a speed thing specific to the PS4. For what its worth, i'll try the foil signal booster, got a link?

Comment: sorry, didn't see the link, thanks João

Comment: Sounds like your internet is being filtered, or you've got some extra management happening at the ISP end.

Comment: @Frank that sounds like a "there's nothing you can do about it" scenario...

Comment: Well, you could always call them up and see.  They could be doing it accidentally.

Comment: @JoãoNeves ok the foil bumped it up 2 Mb, but that puts it at 4 not the old 10 - ill make sure that goes in a final answer though

Comment: @Frank I'll have to do that tomorrow, I'll let you know if something happens, thanks

Comment: @Frank Ok, so I did a combo of everything: in the processing of fixing a few days ago, I changed the settings mentioned in the question. Now, after tinkering for a few hours, I managed to get 10Mb. I'm going to post it as an answer, but I want this to include ANY answer not just the one that fixed mine, so if you two could comment on my answer any alternative methods you can think of, that would be **great**, thanks :)

Comment: @joãoNeves could only notify one user, read above comment ^^

Comment: One thing to note is that Speedtest itself is not always reliable. Check out www.fast.com (powered by Netflix, a company that doesn't have any deals with ISPs) or http://speedtest.xfinity.com/

Answer (score 2):

I used to work for an ISP and there are some things that I can suggest assuming that you did not change anything yourself:
- for best connection never use Wifi
- do a speedtest from a wired machine that is not your PS4 and check the speed is at a minimum the same as you had before the problem if it is not
- ensure that nothing has changed on the router on your end (check the config) and
- call your ISP/provider and ask them to check if your subscription is still the same, if this is the case ask them to check the connection it is possible that due to the problems they had that your connection is configured at a lower speed

Answer (score 0):

One other thing I can recommend that hasn't already been posted is port forwarding. It requires a little network savvyness with your router, but it helps to clear up the channels (ports) that the PS4 needs open to connect to the Internet.

http://portforward.com/english/applications/port_forwarding/PS4/

It may not help with your down and up speeds, but by opening up your NAT type, you may connect to games more easily/stop seeing that annoying weak connection message.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience PS4's signal reception really sucks, so, my suggestion is to buy a switch and connect it via cable.

Comment: It's true, the PS4 really isn't that good with connection quality - even at the best of times, the results of its speed test are about 40% lower than my actual internet speed. Unfortunately for me, the house I live in was made years before the internet was ever considered practical, and so there is only 2 ports in the whole house. None of them are near me. I DID end up fixing it up (still not as good as it used to be), it included everything up to an including putting aluminium foil behind it

Comment: Are there many devices connected to this WIFI network, getting one just for your PS4 might make things better

Comment: Well, I'm sure it would help, but then I'd have to dish out the money on an entirely separate router just for my PS4. As it is, there are 2.4 and 5Ghz networks. Unfortunately the PS4 can't pick up a the 5g network, otherwise I'd connect it to that. As it is, I've put as many devices as I can on the 5g network and left the PlayStation on the 2.4. It has seemed to help a little.

Comment: Buying a new one only for this purpose is definitely not worth it, I meant, just try to disconnect as many devices from the network as you can when using the PS4.

Comment: Ah I see. The only issue with that is that I'm one of four people living in my house, and only 2 of us use the Play Station. I'd never convince the others to disconnect for the sake of video games. But yes, that's a valid solution in most cases

Comment: Well, you can try replacing PS4's antenna, although i really believe you should rethink about the cable solution. You can get a ethernet cable up to 100m long and if you don't have conduits inside your walls you can just leave it exposed and only plug it when playing.

Comment: Fair call. If it were up to me, I would run a cable from the PS4 to the Ethernet cable. Except the other people would really not like loose cable linking the walls. It's about 26m to the closest port, which is where the modem is plugged in. The only other port is literally the opposite side of the house, with a home phone plugged in. I'd have to unplug the phone, or else there's no other way. But eventually we will do renovations, and I'm going to have far more ports installed around the place

Answer (score -1):

Ideas:

- Get a Wifi repeater (extends the Wifi signal to be stronger near your PS4)
- Get a Wifi bridge with better reception than your PS4 - it's similar to a router except reversed - connect your PS4 to the bridge by cable.
- Get power-line adapters - transfers ethernet signal over the power cabling in your house. Performance depends on the house.

Answer (score -2):

Change your network port to 8.8.8.8 or something like that and the one below as 8.8.4.4

That's Google network speed and its super fast. All downloads will be so much faster.

Here's a link: http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/Consoles-Peripherals/How-to-improve-PS4-download-speeds-Works-for-most/td-p/43701250

Comment: OP already did this and it didn't work.